# Looping through hyperlinks in a data frame

Tags: web-scraping

Looping through hyperlinks in a data frame

```
for link in df.iterrows():
    driver.get(link[1]['profileUrl'])
    src=driver.page_source
    soup= BeautifulSoup(src,'html.parser')
    exp_section=soup.find('section',{'id': 'experience-section'})
    exp_section=exp_section.find('ul')

    li_tags=exp_section.find('div')
    a_tags= li_tags.find('a')
    job_title=a_tags.find('h3').get_text().strip()
    company_name=a_tags.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip()
    joining_date=a_tags.find_all('h4')[0].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
    exp=a_tags.find_all('h4')[1].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: It seems an object returns None. How does the structure look like for each website?

Comment: They are all linkedin sites